# Can not make fputcsv via ajax call

Tags: fputcsv

I am trying to output CSV file using another php file called from ajax from another page. Isn't that possible ? When I tried it didn't output CSV file. But via ajax response could see the proper values for CSV file spelled from the called page. Really getting crazy.